# Unable to add rows C# DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm working on this little C# project for work and i need to add data to a `DataGridView` control. I had it working before but sadly since i made some changes on my code, i don't remember how i had it before. All i remember is that in VisualStudio i was going back into the `Form.Designer.cs` and changing some controls to `public static` before testing so i could add rows. I read something online regarding that and they suggested to not do that so that's why i changed my code.

Anyhow moving forward, i have the main Class `AutoCheck.cs` which has the methods:

```
public void addNASDestination(string[] info){
        /*string[0] = Name
        * string[1] = Path
        * string[2] = Username
        * string[3] = Password - Needs to be passed to XML encrypted. Not displayed in the table at all
        */
        destinationsTable.Rows.Add(info[0], "NAS", info[1], info[2], info[3]);
        destinationsTable.Update();
        destinationsTable.Refresh();
        checkTableRowCount();
    }

public void addBDRDestination(string[] info){
        /*string[0] = Name
        * string[1] = Path
        */
        destinationsTable.Rows.Add(info[0], "BDR", info[1]);
        //destinationsTable.Update();
        //destinationsTable.Refresh();
        checkTableRowCount();
    }
```

These methods once worked to add rows to the `DataGridView`. The `info` array value is passed from another Class called `AddDialog.cs` from the method:

```
private void destAddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ac = new AutoCheck();
        if(destNameTextbox.TextLength <= 0 || destNameTextbox.Text == null){
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a name","Error",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }else if(destPathTextbox.TextLength <= 0 || destPathTextbox.Text == null){
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a path", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }else if (!Directory.Exists(destPathTextbox.Text)){
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a valid path", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }else if (isNAS())
        {
            if((destUserTextbox.TextLength <= 0 || destUserTextbox.Text == null) || (destPassTextbox.TextLength <= 0 || destPassTextbox.Text == null)){
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Username and Password", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }else{
                //If Name and User/Pass are good, add info to temp array and pass by reference to addNASDestination
                string[] temp = new string[] { destNameTextbox.Text, destPathTextbox.Text, destUserTextbox.Text, AutoCheck.Encrypt(destPassTextbox.Text) };
                ac.addNASDestination(temp);
                this.Dispose();
            }
        }else{
            //Assume its a BDR and add info to temp array and pass by reference to addBDRDestination
            string[] temp = new string[] {destNameTextbox.Text,destPathTextbox.Text};
            ac.addBDRDestination(temp);
            this.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

`AddDialog` is as the name describes, a dialog that asks the user for input, it then grabs the input and puts it in an array, passes the array by reference to `addBDRDestination` or `addNASDestination` and they should add the new row to the `DataGridView`.

This is not working for me and i have tried to see if the data is even being sent over to `addBDRDestination` or `addNASDestination` by the use of `Console.WriteLine` to output the data being passed and *it is* reaching those methods but the new row is not being added.

I tried refreshing the `DataGridView` by adding this (This is also still on my posted code):

```
destinationsTable.Update();
destinationsTable.Refresh();
```

I also tried this tutorial: http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-add-column.htm
Its about the same as what I'm doing now but it adds the whole array instead of breaking it down the way i do.

I also tried creating a `DataRow` as shown here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f12158b3-4510-47cb-b152-409489c3a51a/how-to-add-rows-in-datagridview-programmatically?forum=winformsdatacontrols

```
DataRow dr = this.dt.NewRow();
dr["a"] = "ax";
dr["b"] = "add item";
destinationsTable.Rows.Add(dr);
```

I tried enabling and disabling `AllowUserToAddRows` but that had no effect.

I also tried this:

```
DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)destinationsTable.Rows[0].Clone();
row.Cells[0].Value = info[0];
row.Cells[1].Value = "BDR";
row.Cells[2].Value = info[1];
destinationsTable.Rows.Add(row);
```

I'm not too sure what else i can try as this worked for me before and now its not.

I think its worth mentioning that `AddDialog.cs` and `AutoCheck.cs` are different class/source files but are in the same namespace `AutoCheck`.

In `AddDialog.cs` im accessing methods from `AutoCheck.cs` by adding `AutoCheck ac = new AutoCheck();`. And the same goes for `AutoCheck` to `AddDialog`.

Is there any other way i can add rows? or maybe I'm doing something wrong with my current code? Many thanks!

Comment: Did you add your columns? Viewable at DataGridView.Columns. And please, add your throwed exception, when there is one.

Comment: Well i did add the columns already in the designer if that's what you're talking about. Unless i need to define them again when adding rows. As for exceptions, i don't get any exceptions and not sure what exception to add if i manually add a try catch clause.

Comment: When there is no error occured, then you should overthink your design. It is cirtical, that we can not look in your code for the specific problem. Debug through your methods until your row should be added. Or rewrite your code.

Comment: eh ok? Do you have any code that has worked for you in the past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which problem you  are facing:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dgv.Columns.Add("cell_one", "Cell 1");
            dgv.Columns.Add("cell_two", "Cell 2");
            dgv.Columns.Add("cell_three", "Cell 3");
            dgv.Columns.Add("cell_four", "Cell 4");
            dgv.Columns.Add("cell_five", "Cell 5");
            addNASDestination(new string[] { "1", "3", "4", "5" });
        }

        public void addNASDestination(string[] info)
        {
            /*string[0] = Name
            * string[1] = Path
            * string[2] = Username
            * string[3] = Password - Needs to be passed to XML encrypted. Not displayed in the table at all
            */
            dgv.Rows.Add(info[0], "NAS", info[1], info[2], info[3]);
            //checkTableRowCount();
        }
    }
```

It compiles and works as expected.

---

Even this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("main");
            dt.Columns.Add("column_one", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("column_two", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("column_three", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("column_four", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("column_five", typeof(string));
            dgv.DataSource = dt;
            addAnyRow();
        }

        public void addAnyRow() {
            var dt = (DataTable)dgv.DataSource;
            var row = dt.NewRow();
            row["column_one"] = "1";
            row["column_two"] = "2";
            row["column_three"] = "3";
            row["column_four"] = "4";
            row["column_five"] = "5";
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

---

Here I seperated them:

```
namespace StackOverflow___46658777
{
    public static class Global
    {
        public static DataGridView DestinationTable;
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1(bool dataTableOrManual = false)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Global.DestinationTable = dgv;

            if (dataTableOrManual) {
                var dt = new DataTable("main");
                dt.Columns.Add("column_one", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("column_two", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("column_three", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("column_four", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("column_five", typeof(string));
                dgv.DataSource = dt;
                new TAutoCheck().AddAnyRow();
                new TAutoCheck().AddAnyRow();
                new TAutoCheck().AddAnyRow();
            } else {
                dgv.Columns.Add("cell_one", "Cell 1");
                dgv.Columns.Add("cell_two", "Cell 2");
                dgv.Columns.Add("cell_three", "Cell 3");
                dgv.Columns.Add("cell_four", "Cell 4");
                dgv.Columns.Add("cell_five", "Cell 5");
                new TAutoCheck().AddNASDestination(new string[] { "1", "3", "4", "5" });
            }
        }
    }

    public class TDialog : Form
    {
        public TDialog()
        {
            //anyButton.Click += validateRequest;
        }

        void validateRequest(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            new TAutoCheck().AddNASDestination(new string[] { "your", "validated", "strings", "are", "here" });
        }
    }

    public class TAutoCheck
    {
        public TAutoCheck() { }

        public void AddAnyRow()
        {
            var dt = (DataTable)Global.DestinationTable.DataSource;
            var row = dt.NewRow();
            row["column_one"] = "1";
            row["column_two"] = "2";
            row["column_three"] = "3";
            row["column_four"] = "4";
            row["column_five"] = "5";
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        public void AddNASDestination(string[] info)
        {
            /*string[0] = Name
            * string[1] = Path
            * string[2] = Username
            * string[3] = Password - Needs to be passed to XML encrypted. Not displayed in the table at all
            */
            Global.DestinationTable.Rows.Add(info[0], "NAS", info[1], info[2], info[3]);
            //checkTableRowCount();
        }
    }
}
```

Works as expected. I hope it is as near as you seperated them, because you did not tell much about how your communication is between your classes and DataGridView. Seperate the classes in own sourcefiles does not change the behaviour of the classes and functions inside.

Comment: Separate them. The way i have it is they are on different source files, different class but same namespace. Yea if you keep it all in the same class, of course it works but that is not how i have it setup.

Comment: Is your DataTable binded to your DataGridView.DataSource? You are talking about about two classes, where do you define/bind your DataTable to the DataGridView? You should only use this one and the same DataTable unless you bind another DataTable to DataGridView.DataSource.

Comment: Seperate classes or logic in sourcefiles are no reason for not being functional unless you make misstakes by design and breaks the communication between classes. Take a look at the edited answer. Try to adapt from it.

Comment: i initially never needed to specify a DataTable and it worked without doing so. I will try this tonight.

Comment: I ended up moving the Form into the same class instead.